# Difference between PageNumber and PageCount in iTextSharp document

Tags: c#, documentation, itext

Where is the difference between properties `PageNumber` and ``PageCount`in`com.itextpdf.text.Document` ? The documentation I have found on this is not very clear.

**Note:**Same properties are also in class `PdfWriter` so I guess that those in `Document` only calls those in `PdfWriter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with the control you mention, but from properties' name I can assume, that PageNumber is the number of current page (for example 1st, 2nd etc) and PageCount is the total number of pages in document (for example 5 pages).

Comment: Well I'm not sure is this can be assumed from property name. The point here is that both such properties would always hold same value. That's because the pages are created one after another and the last one is always "current page".

Comment: On top of the previous comment, the values are both 0 on Document (in my experience). Only the PdfWriter gives correct PageNumber values, and Document.PageCount has no getter.